# Fixing a clustergram column label misalignment

Tags: matlab, alignment, customization, matlab-figure, heatmap

In the code below I try to highlight a specific column by red. However, the resulting label color bar is not aligned with the labels, as shown in the image. How can I correct this?

```
datdat = randn(5,10);
regregnames = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
colors = cell(1,size(datdat,2));
for i=1:size(datdat,2)
    colors{i} = [1,1,1];
end
colors{3} = [1,0,0];
s.Labels = arrayfun(@num2str, 1:size(datdat,2), 'UniformOutput', false);
s.Colors = colors;
clscls = clustergram(datdat, 'RowLabels', regregnames, 'ColumnLabels', s.Labels, 'ColumnLabelsColor', s, 'LabelsWithMarkers', true);
```

[image: Image with misalignment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in MATLAB. How do I know? By inspecting the `clustergram.plot` function.

If we set a breakpoint on line 142, `positionAxes(obj, imAxes)`, and run your code until that point, we get the following figure:

[image: Intermediate plot with correct positioning of the bottom bar]

where the alignment is correct, but the dendrogram is not visible. Then, the code proceeds to reposition the axes (mainly making them smaller), while unfortunately neglecting the bottom part with the red label.

To understand how to fix this, we should go a bit back, into `HeatMap.plot > initHMAxes` where this bottom bar is created and find where its handle is stored. Then, all we need to do is adjust the `position` of this element in accordance with the rest of the `clustergram` (`HeatMap`).

I'll leave digging through the handles/appdata "as an exercise to the reader", but long story short, just add this to the end of your code:

```
hAx = struct(clscls).HMAxesHandle;
data = getappdata(hAx, 'HeatMapAxesData');
data.XMarkerAxes.Position = data.XMarkerAxes.Position.*[0 1 0 1] + hAx.Position.*[1 0 1 0];
```

The result:

[image: The desired result]

---

BTW, on R2017b I'm getting the following warning:

```
Warning: COLUMNLABELSCOLOR is not supported and will be removed in a future release.
Use LabelsWithMarkers for similar functionality.
```

So technically this is not a bug, but rather an unsupported feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, the reason why the function is not being fixed could be because it will be removed anyways, but I am already setting 'LabelsWithMarkers' parameter to 'true' while calling clustergram(), and I could not really figure out how not to use 'ColumnLabelsColor' parameter and get the same functionality with a true/false parameter 'LabelsWithMarkers'. It looks like the documentation does not explain that.